# Wordpress Fatal errors

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, web, warnings

I was editing the file map.php when I started getting errors. So I when to my FTP and delete map.php from it. Now I am having this error. I can't get access to neither my admin panel nor my website. Here is the URL : http://eyeandretina.com.au/

```
Warning: Class 'WPBMap' not found in /home/eyeandre/public_html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/helpers/helpers_api.php on line 17
```

UPDATE :The error seems to be in the directory js_composer

Comment: Some code would be helpful where the errors are so we can help you! (`shortcodes.php` at least like line 10-20 (So if the error is before that line and we see closing `}` from if statements and so on) and if the file isn't to big put the entire file here.)

Comment: You know there is a `edit` button under your question ... (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27579100/edit)

Comment: @So you said that you deleted `map.php` ? If yes make a comment out if this line in your code so that it don't get executed! (`require_once(locate_template("shortcodes/map.php"));` line 17)

Comment: Any Idea? I dont know how to solve this...

Comment: I actually did but now im having this error : http://eyeandretina.com.au/

Comment: I'm not really a wordpress expert, but isn't that a plugin? If yes re-install it?

Comment: Well I tried to remove the plugin completely, but then i got those errors.

Comment: Last idea would be to download the entire plugin again and just change the `map.php`.

Comment: Better idea is to rename the plugin folder, it may conflict with someother plugin also we never know :)

Comment: Thanks Fresher That gave me access to the admin panel. But how will I know which file is causing the conflict?

Comment: I will re-install the plugins 1 by 1. Thanks Fresher, that help me a lot.

Comment: Glad you been sort out solution :)

Comment: Your plugin is calling a class that doesn't exist. Find out why the class is missing.

Comment: [try the answers here](http://themeforest.net/item/oxygen-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/7851484/comments?filter=all&site=themeforest.net&term=Warning%3A+Class+%27WPBMap%27+not+found&utf8=%E2%9C%93) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to first rename the folder where the plugin lives, aka (js_composer) to (js_composer_old) or something like that.

Check your site, if the error was in that plugin indeed, the website should now be able to load and you can access your admin.

You might have some functionality missing because you just deactivated the JS visual composer plugin.

Next, reupload the plugin from your local theme backup/original download file. Or maybe your theme offers autoinstallers from within the admin panel.